# Risk of using native Array prototype method on other objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, native, function-prototypes

I have made a lot of jQuery special events, and now I am trying to make them jQuery plugins.

My code is:

```
$.each("down move hold up tap swipeUp swipeDown swipeLeft swipeRight drag dragCell".split(" "), function(key, value) {
    $.fn[value] = function() {
        var args = [value].concat(Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments,0));
        if ( $.isFunction(arguments[0]) || $.isFunction(arguments[1]) ) {
            return this.bind.apply(this, args);
        } else {
            return this.trigger.apply(this, args);
        }
    };
});
```

Where I loops an array of names (down, move, hold, up, etc...) and dynamically creates jQuery plugins.

As you can see a take the value and name the plugin after it: `$.fn.down`, `$.fn.move`, etc..

Then I take the arguments and loop it through a native array method.

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0);
```

This returns a native Array `[arguments[0], arguments[1], ...]`

And `concat` it with the `value` and ends up with:

```
["down", arguments[0], arguments[1], ...],
["move", arguments[0], arguments[1], ...],
....
```

Is there any risk of doing this (using native methods and other objects then meant), and is there any possibility of losing data?

As you can see it messes with jQuery's `bind` and `trigger` methods. Is this also dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i close this question: A way to achieve the same for arguments is:

Thanks to [raynos](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/419970/raynos)

```
var toArray = function (obj) {
  var ret = new Array(obj.length);
  for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    ret[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

toArray(arguments);
```